# Grab a property of a Delete HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I am looking to test the output of one of my API requests below.

```
async Task DeleteNonExistantFoo()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("Http://localhost:43240/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.DeleteAsync("api/foos/1"))
        {
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //Assert.AreEqual(?????, "A Foo with ID of 1 does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to grab the exceptionMessage from the response below, which is given as a response when I send a DELETE request to the API. When debugging in visual studio it won't let me look at the response content object, giving me the error

> "responseContent   Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.
>   "

Do I need to convert it to a JSON object to read it?

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "A Foo with ID of 1 does not exist.",
    "exceptionType": "System.Exception",
    "stackTrace": "
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your _exact_ code but be careful with newing up a `HttpClient` for every request, its actually a [performance and stability concern](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).  You should be using a shared static HttpClient (but be aware of [the DNS problem that arises from that](http://www.nimaara.com/2016/11/01/beware-of-the-net-httpclient/))

Comment: Is it possible to initialize the HTTP Client in the ClassInitalize method of the unit test class and have all the tests use that HTTP client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `Newtonsoft.Json` of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method to read response Json translate to an object and use it.

create a class `ApiResponeMoedl`

```
public class ApiResponeMoedl
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string exceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public string exceptionType { get; set; }
    public string stackTrace { get; set; }
}
```

then using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponeMoedl>` deserialize your json data to an `ApiResponeMoedl` object, then use object's `exceptionMessage` property you will get your desert information.

```
async Task DeleteNonExistantRedirect()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("Http://localhost:43240/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.DeleteAsync("api/foos/1"))
        {
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var respOjb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponeMoedl>(responseContent);
            //respOjb.exceptionMessage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I run that code and try to debug it I get this error Message: Test method Website.Test.Api.FooApiControllerTest.DeleteMethodFoo threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What json data did you get when you running and getting a error? Is it the sample as your question?

Comment: responseContent = "" and responseObj = null, I still get the same httpresponse when testing the API in postman

Comment: Ive tried it over and over and it eventually worked when I tried it on a different item in the database. Ill let you know if I run into any other errors. Thanks!